# Punching bag or cramped space

Tags: training, self-defense

I'm stuck in my small apartment these days (Covid + there's a lot of snow outside), and I'd like to find a way to set up a punching bag, but I don't have much space and the ceiling doesn't have any mounting points. Can someone recommend a good way to do this? I'm a heavyweight and I punch and kick fairly hard, so it can't be too flimsy either...

Up to now I've been moving the furniture to get a bit of temporary shadow boxing space in my living room, but that doesn't really satisfy my needs.

Comment: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/recommendations-for-quiet-punching-kickboxing-bags/9812#9812

Comment: Do you have a spare mattress? You can easily get a free one somewhere. Put it up against the wall and it works great as a punching surface. You can throw front kicks too. And trust me, you can you much more harder and faster on it as it doesn't move around.